# Should I use complete partition for a Wubi Install?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, wubi

I have a completely free partition of 19.5 Gb (Windows is installed in another partition.) When I start Wubi, it suggests that I use about 12 Gb for Ubuntu.

The question is: Should I go with Wubi's suggestion or should I use the maximum possible that Wubi is allowing me (19 Gb)?

Also Wubi isn't letting me set a custom size (like 13.8 Gb for example). Is there a way around it?

Comment: dual boot is the best way to go in my opinion.

Comment: @Alvar Wubi will create dual-boot all right. I am asking about the partition space.

Comment: Wubi will create a "new" partition but it will be inside the NTFS space. so it's not a dual-boot setup. If you want a dual-boot go with the Live-CD/USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main advantages of wubi is that you do not have to repartition and then can uninstall it with Windows and recover all the file space. It exists just as a file (root.disk) inside the Windows NTFS partition.

If you have a separate partition, it really is better to do a full dual boot install to that partition, even the developer of wubi expects you to do that.
From the developer of wubi:

http://howsoftwareisbuilt.com/2009/03/12/interview-with-agostino-russo-wubi-ubuntu/

Agostino: Wubi actually wasn’t designed to do long-term installations. The main aim was really to let people try out Ubuntu with confidence. Normally, users that start with Wubi tend to upgrade to a full installation to a dedicated partition at the next release cycle.

More info on wubi:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression WUBI was installed in the existing windows partition not in a separate partition on it's own. The OP probably is referring to Dual Boot not WUBI

Comment: that's correct.